# Pass data in URL without using GET

Tags: php

I have a page that displays information for a selected member.  Right now, I choose select the member in the URL using GET data like so: `Page/index.php?Member=member1`  I see websites that do it like this: `Page/member1`  Is this possible to do with only one PHP file?

Comment: It can be done in PHP - see my post but it is not clean and could be error prone.

Answer (score 3):

Friendly URLs need some kind of processing by the webserver so that the page requests are channeled through a single php script (aka controller).

For example, Apache has the ability to match patterns in the URL and modify the request behind the scenes - you would actually write the PHP to react as if the user had entered the original GET string, but they can use the friendly URL instead.

Simple example for Apache - put a .htaccess in your document root and write:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   ^Page/([A-Za-z0-9\_]+)/?$   index.php?member=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I don't know what the equivalent would be in IIS - but I am aware that it is available

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done with just PHP - you do this with mod_rewrite and usually .htacess on apache.

Comment: Post below mine answered on how to do a rewrite with apache

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this, all of which depend on the web server. With Apache, some possibilities:

- mod_rewrite (most flexible way, but can be tedious to configure)
- Option +MultiView (very easy, but requires PHP files to be named similar to the requested URL)
- custom 404 handler (not recommended)

Say you are using Apache and have enabled MultiView. The file `Page.php` would be a match for `Page/*`, which would obviously include `Page/member1`. You would then have to inspect the URL (look at `$_SERVER`, it has everything you need) and decide if you can honor the request.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in PHP alone using the following:

1.) Get filename relative to the document root.

```
$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']
```

http://example.com/test.php/foo.bar would be /test.php/foo.bar.

2.) Explode by your delimiter (in this case /)

```
array explode  ( string $delimiter  , string $string  [, int $limit  ] )
```

3.) Verify values in array and then place into variables

```
var $myValue = myarray[0];
```